# returning user instead of True or False in Django Permission class

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, permissions

I have a custom permission class which I am importing in one of the views. In that permission class, I am using return user instead of True or False. But it seems to be working. But I dont really understand why.

The class is as follows:

```
class ExamplePermission(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        user = CustomUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()

        if view.action == 'list':
            return user

        elif request.method == 'POST' or 'PATCH' or view.action == 'destroy' or 'update':
            return user and user.user_type == ADMIN

        else:
            return False
```

Here in above permission class , I am returning user in some places instead of boolean true or false. What is the meaning of returning user? How it is still working??

Comment: `user` is a `CustomUser` object. By default a class object has *truthiness* `True`, so `if someCustomUser` will be evaluate to `True`.

Comment: Ie it works, right??

Comment: Probably not as you're expecting it to since `'PATCH'` is always true

Comment: No, of course not, I didn't catch that @Sayse.  It should be `if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'PATCH' ...`

Comment: so if i am using "patch" then i shoudlnt write like `elif request.method == 'POST' or 'PATCH' or`

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's `'PATCH'`, @Reactoo, it's just the way you are forming your condition that is incorrect.  Check out my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work.  Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing.  As long as `user` is not empty it will return `True`.

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
> either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method
> that returns zero, when called with the object.

So even though the object `user` is NOT a `Boolean`, it will be treated as such when doing any logical comparisons.

In fact this is a way one often [checks to see if a queryset is empt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists)y:

```py
if some_queryset:
    print("There is at least one object in some_queryset")
```

Although, as the docs say, the [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists) method is a bit faster, and better, *if you don't need the actual queryset, and just want to know if the queryset is empty or not*.

**EDIT**
To answer your question you posted in the comment, you must separate each condition you are testing in the `if .. or`:  In other words, if you want to test if A equals B or C or D, the you cannot do:

```py
if A == B or C or D
```

Instead you must do,

```py
if A == B or A == C or A == D
```

Thus your code should look like this:

```py
class ExamplePermission(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        user = CustomUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()

        if view.action == 'list':
            return user

        elif request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'PATCH' or view.action == 'destroy' or view.action == 'update':
            return user and user.user_type == ADMIN

        else:
            return False
```